# Making an .exe for pygame with cx-freeze

Tags: python, pygame, exe, cx-freeze

I've created a game in Python 3.2 and tried to turn it into a .exe with cx-freeze but when I try to run the .exe, I get an error.

The Game

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()

windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
pygame.display.set_caption("Dodger")

def game():
    WIDTH = 800
    HEIGHT = 800
    PLAYERSIZE = 20
    PLAYERSPEED = 4
    ENEMYSIZE = 10
    ENEMYSPEED = 3
    score = 0

    BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
    WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
    GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
    RED = (255, 0, 0)
    GREY = (100, 100, 100)
    BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

    Up = False
    Down = False
    Left = False
    Right = False

    titleFont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 100)
    titleText = titleFont.render('Dodger', True, WHITE)
    titleRect = titleText.get_rect()
    titleRect.centerx = windowSurface.get_rect().centerx
    titleRect.centery = 50

    menuFont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 70)
    startText = menuFont.render('Start', True, WHITE)
    startRect = startText.get_rect()
    startRect.centerx = windowSurface.get_rect().centerx
    startRect.centery = 213

    difficultyText = menuFont.render('Difficulty', True, WHITE)
    difficultyRect = difficultyText.get_rect()
    difficultyRect.centerx = windowSurface.get_rect().centerx
    difficultyRect.top = 320

    quitText = menuFont.render('Quit', True, WHITE)
    quitRect = quitText.get_rect()
    quitRect.centerx = windowSurface.get_rect().centerx
    quitRect.centery = 582

    oneText = menuFont.render('1', True, WHITE)
    oneRect = oneText.get_rect()
    oneRect.centerx = 250
    oneRect.centery = 421

    twoText = menuFont.render('2', True, WHITE)
    twoRect = twoText.get_rect()
    twoRect.centerx = 350
    twoRect.centery = 421

    threeText = menuFont.render('3', True, WHITE)
    threeRect = threeText.get_rect()
    threeRect.centerx = 450
    threeRect.centery = 421

    fourText = menuFont.render('4', True, WHITE)
    fourRect = fourText.get_rect()
    fourRect.centerx = 550
    fourRect.centery = 421

    difficulty = 1
    loop = 1

    while loop:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                posX, posY  = pos
                if posY > 390 and posY < 452:
                    if posX > 200 and posX < 300:
                        difficulty = 1
                    elif posX > 300 and posX < 400:
                        difficulty = 2
                    elif posX > 400 and posX < 500:
                        difficulty = 3
                    elif posX > 500 and posX < 600:
                        difficulty = 4
                elif posY > 120 and posY < 306 and posX > 120 and posX < WIDTH - 120:
                    loop = 0
                elif posY > 492 and posY < WIDTH - 120 and posX > 120 and posX < WIDTH - 120:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == ord('1'):
                    difficulty = 1
                elif event.key == ord('2'):
                    difficulty = 2
                elif event.key == ord('3'):
                    difficulty = 3
                elif event.key == ord('4'):
                    difficulty = 4
                elif event.key == K_RETURN:
                    loop = 0

        if difficulty == 1:
            choiceRect = pygame.Rect(201, 391, 99, 61)
        elif difficulty == 2:
            choiceRect = pygame.Rect(301, 391, 99, 61)
        elif difficulty == 3:
            choiceRect = pygame.Rect(401, 391, 99, 61)
        elif difficulty == 4:
            choiceRect = pygame.Rect(501, 391, 99, 61)

        windowSurface.fill(BLACK)
        #draw main menu box
        pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, WHITE, (120, 120), (WIDTH - 120, 120))
        pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, WHITE, (120, 120), (120, HEIGHT - 120))
        pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, WHITE, (WIDTH - 120, HEIGHT - 120), (120, HEIGHT - 120))
        pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, WHITE, (WIDTH - 120, HEIGHT - 120), (WIDTH - 120, 120))

        #draw lines to divide menu
        pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, WHITE, (120, 306), (WIDTH - 120, 306))
        pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, WHITE, (120, 492), (WIDTH - 120, 492))

        pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, WHITE, (200, 390), (WIDTH - 200, 390))
        pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, WHITE, (200, 452), (WIDTH - 200, 452))
        pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, WHITE, (200, 390), (200, 452))
        pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, WHITE, (WIDTH - 200, 390), (WIDTH - 200, 452))
        pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, WHITE, (300, 390), (300, 452))
        pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, WHITE, (400, 390), (400, 452))
        pygame.draw.line(windowSurface, WHITE, (500, 390), (500, 452))

        pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, GREY, choiceRect)
        windowSurface.blit(titleText, titleRect)
        windowSurface.blit(startText, startRect)
        windowSurface.blit(difficultyText, difficultyRect)
        windowSurface.blit(quitText, quitRect)
        windowSurface.blit(oneText, oneRect)
        windowSurface.blit(twoText, twoRect)
        windowSurface.blit(threeText, threeRect)
        windowSurface.blit(fourText, fourRect)
        pygame.display.update()

    difficulty += 1
    Player = pygame.Rect((WIDTH/2)-(PLAYERSIZE/2),(HEIGHT/2) - (PLAYERSIZE/2), PLAYERSIZE, PLAYERSIZE)
    enemies = []
    for enemy in range(0, difficulty):
        if enemy == 1:
            enemies.append(pygame.Rect(1, 1, ENEMYSIZE, ENEMYSIZE))
        elif enemy == 2:
            enemies.append(pygame.Rect(WIDTH - PLAYERSIZE, 1, ENEMYSIZE, ENEMYSIZE))
        elif enemy == 3:
            enemies.append(pygame.Rect(1, HEIGHT - PLAYERSIZE, ENEMYSIZE, ENEMYSIZE))
        elif enemy == 4:
            enemies.append(pygame.Rect(WIDTH - PLAYERSIZE, HEIGHT - PLAYERSIZE, ENEMYSIZE, ENEMYSIZE))

    loop = 1
    while loop:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                    Up = True
                    Down = False
                if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                    Down = True
                    Up = False
                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                    Left = True
                    Right = False
                if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                    Right = True
                    Left = False

            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                    Up = False
                if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                    Down = False
                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                    Left = False
                if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                    Right = False
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    pygame.exit()

        if Up and Player.top >= 0:
            Player.top -= PLAYERSPEED
        if Down and Player.bottom <= HEIGHT:
            Player.bottom += PLAYERSPEED
        if Left and Player.left >= 0:
            Player.left -= PLAYERSPEED
        if Right and Player.right <= WIDTH:
            Player.right += PLAYERSPEED

        i = 0
        for enemy in enemies:
            if enemies[i].top > Player.top:
                enemies[i].top -= ENEMYSPEED
            if enemies[i].top < Player.top:
                enemies[i].top += ENEMYSPEED
            if enemies[i].left > Player.left:
                enemies[i].left -= ENEMYSPEED
            if enemies[i].left < Player.left:
                enemies[i].left += ENEMYSPEED
            i += 1


        windowSurface.fill(BLACK)
        pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, GREEN, Player)

        i = 0
        for enemy in enemies:
            pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, RED, enemies[i])
            if Player.colliderect(enemies[i]):
                loop = 0
            i += 1

        pygame.display.update()
        mainClock.tick(40)
        score += 1

    score = str(score)
    endRect = pygame.Rect(windowSurface.get_rect().centerx - 250, windowSurface.get_rect().centery - 75, 500, 150)
    scoreText = menuFont.render('Score: ' + score, True, RED)
    scoreRect = scoreText.get_rect()
    scoreRect.centerx = windowSurface.get_rect().centerx
    scoreRect.centery = windowSurface.get_rect().centery

    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, BLUE, endRect)
    windowSurface.blit(scoreText, scoreRect)
    pygame.display.update()

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_RETURN:
                    game()

game()
```

My setup.py

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "Dodger",
    version = "3.2",
    description = "My Game",
    executables = [Executable("dodger.py", base = "Win32GUI")])
```

When I try to run it, a window pops up and I get the following 
[error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sY16.jpg)

Edit:
I added "import pygame._view" to dodger.py and I now get this [error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFJD4.jpg)

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309981/pygame-compiling-to-exe-with-cx-freeze. You just need to add "import pygame._view" in you source code.

Comment: Let me know if that works; I haven't tested it.

Comment: I tried that and still no luck.

Comment: Do you get the same errors if you use Py2EXE?

Comment: Py2EXE is only 2.7, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, that's right. that particular program should run just fine under 2.7, but perhaps it would be best to pursue other routes before asking you to install python2.x, pygame to match, and Py2EXE.

Comment: Ok, I've done some googling. One suggestion I found was to delete all .pyc files on you machine then re-run cx-freeze. If that doesn't work (and I am probing in the dark here), you could try the suggestion this thread makes: https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/9/trouble-with-pyqt4.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your problem is the fact that you do not use a system font. A cx_freeze exe does not know how to read `None` When I had that problem I changed the font from `None` to a system font. The way you could find what fonts are installed on your system is using the script below.

```
import pygame
print(pygame.font.get_fonts()) 
input()
```

The `pygame.font.get_fonts()` will bring up a list of all the system fonts installed. All you have to do is change your `titleFont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 100)` to `titleFont = pygame.font.SysFont('miriam', 100)` or something like that ('miriam' is a font installed on my system).

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention that you must call the pygame.font.Font(font,size) function instead of the pygame.font.SysFont(font, size) function.

Comment: I tried that but am now getting this error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python32\Programs\Dodger\dodger.py", line 252, in <module>
        game()
          File "C:\Python32\Programs\Dodger\dodger.py", line 32, in     game
        titleFont = pygame.font.Font('arial', 100)
    IOError: unable to read font file 'arial'

Comment: Did you use Pygame.font.Font or Pygame.font.SysFont?

Comment: You can see in the error I posted that I used pygame.font.Font('arial', 100)

Comment: My bad. You should use pygame.font.SysFont('arial',100) instead of the other one.I tested it and it worked. pygame.font.Font() is used if you have a font in the same directory. Sorry to mislead you.